# Cant Query XML XElement if loaded by file

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq

The problem is that I don't get any results, if I query following XML code by saved file using VS 2017 latest patches.

```
Dim SettingsFileAsElement As XElement = XElement.Load("MyXmlFile.xml")
```

in VB.NET with LINQ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings>
  <ConnnectionString>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>ConnString 1</Name>
  </ConnnectionString>
</Settings>
```

My query

```
Dim ConnnectionStrings = From ConnnectionString In SettingsAsElement...<ConnnectionString> _
                                Select ConnnectionString
 ' ConnnectionStrings as IEn(Of XElement)
```

works fine, if it is used like a String

```
Dim SettingsAsElement As XElement = <Settings>
                                      <ConnnectionString>
                                         <ID>1</ID>
                                         <Name>ConnString 1</Name>
                                       </ConnnectionString>
                                     </Settings>
```

The opening of the file works fine and I can access all properties.
The point is, if I compare the properties of the XElements (**SettingsFileAsElement vs. SettingsAsElement**) they are identicly.

---

FirstNode From String:        1  ConnString 1

FirstNode From File:          1  ConnString 1

HasAttributes From String:  False

HasAttributes From File:    False

HasElements From String:    True

HasElements From File:      True

IsEmpty From String:        False

IsEmpty From File:          False

LastNode From String:         1  ConnString 1

LastNode From File:           1  ConnString 1

Name From String:           Settings

Name From File:             Settings

NodeType From String:       Element

NodeType From File:         Element

Value From String:          1ConnString 1

Value From File:            1ConnString 1

---

I even tried to access the file with XDocument and query this and then I tried to parse XDocument to XElement. Result was even nothing for both.

I thought this could be by some issues of my project. So I opened a new one. Only for this problem; but nothing works.

Any ideas ? 
BG - Sven

---

Edit:
Working code:

```
    Dim SettingsAsElement As XElement = <Settings>
                                    <ConnnectionString>
                                        <ID>1</ID>
                                        <Name>ConnString 1</Name>
                                    </ConnnectionString>
                                    </Settings>
    '------
        Dim ConnnectionStrings = From ConnnectionString In SettingsAsElement...<ConnnectionString> _
                                Select ConnnectionString

        For Each ConnnectionString In ConnnectionStrings
            ListBox1.Items.Add(ConnnectionString.<Name>.Value)
        Next
   ' returned "data" in ConnnectionStrings = "ConnString 1"
```

Not working code:

```
        Dim SettingsFileAsElement As XElement = XElement.Load(Path)

        ConnnectionStrings = From ConnnectionString In SettingsFileAsElement...<ConnectionString> _
                                    Select ConnnectionString

        For Each ConnnectionString In ConnnectionStrings
            ListBox1.Items.Add(ConnnectionString.<Name>.Value)
        Next
   ' returned "data" in ConnnectionStrings = Nothing
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is.  You say that you can open the file and get the data and that  (SettingsFileAsElement vs. SettingsAsElement)  compares as identical.  Then later you say that the "Result was even nothing".  Can you show the code that is not working?

Comment: Chris; code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file code is missing the misspelling of "ConnnectionString" with 3 "n"s.

Try

```
ConnnectionStrings = From ConnnectionString In SettingsFileAsElement...<ConnnectionString> _
                                    Select ConnnectionString
```

With the 3 "n"s in `<ConnnectionString>`.

Or better yet, fix the misspelling to two "n"s

Comment: arrg, ......
hit my eyes and my brain.. thx !! Cant mark as an answer, cus less rep

Comment: Why can't you mark it as an answer?  Please do if you can.

Comment: done and marked now ( I was looking and clicking to arrows, but as told before: my eyes and brain ..... )

Comment: Thanks for doing that!